# Does Liferay Search Portlet searches in CMIS repository?

Tags: search, liferay, liferay-6, cmis

I have mounted SharePoint and Alfresco repositories in my liferay portal. Now, If I search for any document from Document and Media Search, it is searching from mounted repositories, but if I Search the same from Search portlet it is not searching from mounted repositories.

Do we have any configuration by which we can make Search portlet search into mounted repositories too?

Early reply would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: check search portlet configuration options it might help you

Comment: Please crossreference all the places on the web where you asked the same question. If someone has answered the question there already, we can save the same work at all of the other places. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Linking to your crossposts on the Liferay forums: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/54236660 and https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/54216971. The discussion has already begun there and it would be weird if there would be a second independent discussion here.

Is it too much to ask you to link to other posts that you did at the same time yourself?